# My C code is not working

Tags: c

I'm so confused here. Why this code of mine doesn't work as it SHOULD be..

Here's the code:

```
void print(int x) {

    x = 140;
    int i,total, length, value;   

    if (x < 10){
        value = 0;
    }
    else {
        int sum = 1;
        for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            total = 10 * sum;
            sum = total; 
            length = x / total;
            if (length < 10 && 1 <= length){ 
                value = i+1; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    value = pow(10,value);
    printf("%d\n",value);
}
```

Let me explain how the code should works first:

It takes an integer x and print out the highest power of 10 value it can be divided by.

So if X = 80, it should print 10 and if x = 12435, it should print 10000.
But this doesn't work with my code perfectly... if x = 140, it prints 99 but. if x = 1400, it prints 1000 then again, if x = 14000 it prints 9999 and if x = 140000 it prints 100000 and the sequence continues...

I've already tried exactly the same code in Java and it works perfectly!!
Why does it not works in C??

Comment: To start with, indent your code properly.

Comment: Dry run your code and see where the problem is

Comment: @Zeyad, I think only a drunk coder can write drunk code.

Comment: I actually find this question not so badly asked ... you can see much worse questions everyday.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore LOL - a 'dry' run would require sobering up first.

Comment: Downvoted mostly because of the title. It is very uninformative.

Comment: Yew sh..shuda runn yer codezzz inna debuggggga...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pow() is returning an double value, which you are casting to an integer. So instead of rounding it will be truncated.

You should try

```
value = round(pow(10,value));
```

Comment: There's also the fact that `value` may be uninitialized before it is used.

Comment: downvoting without a comment is nice.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, I downvoted this because you answered a very low quality question. As per the guidelines of Stack Overflow, each and every user must refrain from answering low quality questions. And also note that I love downvoting answers, how much ever correct they are, if they are posted to a low quality post, with the intention of only gaining reputation. This is because, when the OP gets an answer to his low quality question, he will never think of improving his post.But if he gets no answer, for getting an answer he will improve his post. Leading him to follow the rules: Positive Outcome